# Laravel 8 do not worlkig defaults routes

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am trying to make Laravel app with React. I want to start with Registration and Auth forms. So I made these using commands from laravel

composer require laravel/ui

php artisan ui react

php artisan ui react --auth

But unfortunately, smth went wrong and when I am using Login, route for the home page doesn't work.
Where can be the problem?

**App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Login**

```
        <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Login Controller
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
        | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
        | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
        |
        */
    
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
    
        /**
         * Where to redirect users after login.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    
        /**
         * Create a new controller instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
    }
```

**App\Controllers\HomeController**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
}
```

**app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';
//    public const MAIN = '/main';


    /**
     * The controller namespace for the application.
     *
     * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Configure the rate limiters for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function configureRateLimiting()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(60)->by(optional($request->user())->id ?: $request->ip());
        });
    }
}
```

**Views\home**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**routes\web**

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Web Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
    |
    */
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Auth::routes();
    
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    //Route::get('/main', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'main'])->name('main');
```

**routes\api**

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | API Routes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
    | routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
    | is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
    |
    */
    
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
```

**views\auth\login**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>
    
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>
    
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>
    
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
    
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">
    
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                            {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Login') }}
                                    </button>
    
                                    @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                        <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                            {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                        </a>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

That auth scaffolding got replicated in laravel 8

There are other options now you can do auth with. But asyou try to build seperate spa, then fortify will be the best option
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#when-should-i-use-fortify

Answer (score 0):

You can try uncommenting this line in "app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider"

```
// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```